# simulate multiple returns from method with multiple calls using different parameter values?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, patch

I want to test that only valid files are added to a count of valid files, like so:

```
self.n_valid_files = 0
for file in self.list_of_files:
    n_paras = self.count_paras(file)
    if n_paras != None:
        self.n_valid_files += 1
```

where `count_paras` returns `None` if something goes wrong.

Is there a way to patch-and-test that: i.e. supply a multiple given files in `self.list_of_files`, and then say that, for each, `count_paras` should return a particular value?

I.e. something like:

```
my_test_dict = {'filename1': 3, 'filename2': 30, 'filename3': None}
with mock.patch.object(project, 'count_paras') as mock_count:
    mock_count.return_value = my_test_dict[what-might-go-here?] # this doesn't work of course
    project.process_files(my_test_dict.keys())
    ...
```

... the problem being that there are multiple calls to `count_paras` for only one call to `process_files`.

Comment: You can use `side_effect` instead of `return_value` to provide a list of return values that will be used in subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return different values from a mocked function in subsequent calls, you can use [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect). In this case, `side_effect` takes a list of values that are used as return values (it is also possible to use a callable for `side_effect` which will then be called, but that is an unrelated use case).

In your example, you already have the values of your sample dict which you want to use as return values:

```py
def test_count_paras():
    project = Project()
    my_test_dict = {'filename1': 3, 'filename2': 30, 'filename3': None}
    with mock.patch.object(project, 'count_paras') as mock_count:
        mock_count.side_effect = my_test_dict.values()
        project.process_files(my_test_dict.keys())
        assert project.n_valid_files == 2
```

What happens here is that each call to the mocked `count_paras` returns the next value in the list passed to `side_effect`, so in your case 3, 30 and `None`.